# Install Laravel using Composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install Laravel using *Composer*, but after running the following command

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel cmsLaravel 5.2
```

pointing to my `c/xampp/htddocs` directory, I get the error below:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelCMS\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelCMS\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Answer (score 25):

To install Laravel using composer, all you need to do is to run in your terminal is:

```sh
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Where: `blog` is the name of the folder containing your new Laravel instance.

To install Laravel directly within your chosen directory (not in a folder within it as demonstrated above), simply run the same command but this time without a folder name as in:

```sh
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel
```

Remember to run the command within your desired directory for the project; in your case, for `C:\xampp\htdocs\`, then, run either the first or second command as above base on your needs.

*This assumes you already have Composer properly installed as recommended on their [website](https://getcomposer.org/download/).*

Before you try addressing your `failed to open stream:` error, do avoid having folder names with space(s) as in your command above (obviously not the source of the error).

Make sure you have the correct Server Requirements for Laravel

*the `failed to open stream:` error usually occur when the OpenSSL PHP Extension not enabled.*

- PHP >= 5.6.4
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension

After enabling the required extension(s), do remember to restart your server, then run the following command:

```sh
composer update
```

Answer (score 7):

Follow the steps below;

1. Download and install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe).
2. Go inside the folder `C:\xampp\htdocs>`(if you are using xampp) or `C:\wamp\www>`(if you are using wamp) and open cmd/PoweShell & run the following commands:

   - `composer global require "laravel/installer"`
   - `composer create-project laravel/laravel` (after running this command a folder having name Laravel will be created there)
   - Now go inside Laravel folder and run `php artisan serve` command.
3. After executing the last `cmd`, it will show an URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000`; access the URL in a browser, which should reflect the will see the default webpage of Laravel.

Answer (score 5):

1. Download and install [composer](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe)
2. Run `composer global require "laravel/installer"`
3. Open terminal inside C:\xampp\htdocs and run `laravel new my_folder_name`

Comment: still same error Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelCMS\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelCMS\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Comment: You deleted the laravelCMS folder before running `laravel new my_folder_name`? If you have the file composer.json inside the folder laravelCMS you can run `composer install` and this will install required dependencies

Comment: yes but wait my composer.json file is located in C:\Users\FAHAD\AppData\Roaming\Composer , and i update composer like command below C:\Users\FAHAD\AppData\Roaming\Composer>composer update

Comment: This is for global purposes, you should have a composer.json inside the laravelCMS folder which is what will manage the dependencies of that folder. If you not have a composer.json inside that folder probably you have a problem with composer installation, so i sugest you uninstall it and delete this folder C:\Users\FAHAD\AppData\Roaming\Composer, then try again

Comment: Also verify that the system path points to this file C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer

Comment: When I run `laravel new demo`, I get this error: `cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 1080: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcu
  rl-errors.html)`

Answer (score 3):

You can just run

> composer install

and it will process the required files to load the laravel in web browser

EDIT:

After seeing your comment, you should go to your laravel directory in your cmd.

> cd C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelCMS

and run the command

> composer install

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelCMS>composer install             
Composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelCMS
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Comment: my composer.json file is located in C:\Users\FAHAD\AppData\Roaming\Composer can i copy that file into C:\Users\FAHAD\AppData\Roaming\Composer

Comment: @FahadAkram have you ever installed the laravel inside xampp\htdocs\laravelCMS before? if you never install the laravel there before, try to run `C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelCMS>composer global require "laravel/installer"` (including the double quotes), make sure you are on the project directory when trying to run `composer global require "laravel/installer"`

Comment: `composer install` will definitely not work in this instance as per the naration described in the OP as *there is obviously NO composer.json* file since there is not successful project (here, Laravel) creation nor a creation of a `composer.json` file through any other means.

Comment: @nyedidikeke that's why i asked him to try install a clear new project on my comment, as you can see above. Following this tutorial [Laravel Installation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3) won't be a problem

Answer (score 3):

Change your command to this:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel cmsLaravel 5.2.*
```

This mean any sub version of `laravel 5.2`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your index.php and **Change the path as per your project directory**

**Register The Auto Loader**

```
require __DIR__.'/cmsLaravel /vendor/autoload.php'; 
$app =require_once __DIR__.'/cmsLaravel /bootstrap/app.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel 6.0
```

**`composer`** is a tool for dependency management in `PHP`

**`create-project`** is command to create a new laravel project

**`laravel/laravel`** is for the skeleton application you get when creating a new project. It provides a default structure that's recommended (you're not forced to use it). The repository contains default `config` files, `controllers`, `routes`, etc. As well as code responsible for `bootstrapping` the application.

Link [Laravel/laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel)

**`6.0`** Version in laravel

Answer (score 0):

just run your command line as admin
it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

> **Please follow this step and try it**

> **step 1**

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
```

> **step 2**

```
composer global require laravel/installer
 
laravel new example-app
```

> **step 3**

```
cd example-app
 
php artisan serve
```

**Else I will Recommend You To Go in to laravel offical page**

[Clik Here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation)

Comment: What does this add to the existing answers that provide the same? If you'd like to improve an existing answer, please gain some reputation first. And welcome to Stackoverflow!