# Laravel Installation On Windows by using Composer

Tags: laravel

I am trying to setup Laravel using Composer through my command prompt but I am getting some errors.
I have already installed Composer and Xampp(php/mysql/apache) but I am still unable to install it. I have followed the exact instructions provide by the Laravel and followed other resources but I am still getting error.
[image]

Comment: Try followings; `composer clearcache`, delete `vendor` and `composer.lock`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Laravel using Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41975092/install-laravel-using-composer)