# (Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException) Command "new" is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

when i try to create new project with laravel framework i got above error..
How can i solve...
Any path setting process should i take or something else...
can any one mention it properly...
Thanks in advance...

[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87rv3.png)

[Here is my composer installation confirmation message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9bbd.png)

[Here is my laravel confirmation message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zoE8.png)

Comment: Your correct command is `laravel new FreeCodeGram`

Comment: Or, with composer `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel FreeCodeGram`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Laravel using Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41975092/install-laravel-using-composer)